# c++ threading in UDP for real-time video transission

Tags: c++, multithreading, udp

I am currently working on a project of real-time camera video transmission. I have done the camera capturing using opencv and real-time encoding decoding using ffmepg.

Now my problem is that, at the decoder side, I want to let the decoder keep playing the decoded video while keep receiving the encoded packet at the same time. My supervisor told me I need to apply threading to realize this function.

Any idea how should I do this or any example program?

Comment: Read up on threading, and come back with *specific* questions. As it stands right now, your question is far too broad.

Comment: Sorry, can I request to cancel my question, thank you admin.

Comment: I'm not an admin, just another user. But yes, feel free to delete your question.

Comment: Yes, and I can recommend you *"C++Concurrency in action"* from Anthony Williams (who also contributes on SO from time to time).

Comment: thanks a lot for your recommendation !